# How to create materialized view of an external table

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

```
CREATE VIEW materialized_view WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT ...
FROM ext.external_table
```

Fails with

> The option 'SCHEMABINDING' is not supported with external tables.

If I understand correctly SCHEMABINDING is necessary to make a materialized view.
How can I correct this query?

Comment: From [Create Indexed Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15#BeforeYouBegin): "The view must reference only base tables that are in the same database as the view. The view cannot reference other views."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create an indexed view based on tables that are in a different database.

I think your options are:

a) create the indexed view in the other database and create a regular view in this database to query that indexed view

b) create a copy of the table in this database and a mechanism to update this table whenever the data is changed in the table which is in the other database; this could be done with triggers, replication, a stored procedure called on a schedule, etc.